# Always get an empty array in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

There are two columns in the database table "system". I have the `systemId` and want to get the `mobileSystemId`. But the variable `$mobileSystemId`s which I already defined as global is always empty.

EDIT: Now array_map doesn´t work. I always get my Exception output "Arrayfehler ArrayMap"
   I have the following code :

```
$mobileSystemIds=array();

function getMobileSystemId($systemId)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        global $mobileSystemIds;
        $query="SELECT mobileSystemId FROM system WHERE systemId ='" .$systemId ."'";
        if(!$result=$mysqli->query($query))
        {
            echo "Datenbankfehler DB-QUery";
            exit(0);
        }
        if (!$mobileSystemId=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "Datenbankfehler DB-Fetch";
            exit(0);
        }
        $mobileSystemId=$mobileSystemId["mobileSystemId"];
        echo "mobile System ID: " .$mobileSystemId ."<br />";
        return $mobileSystemId; 
    }   

    if(!$mobileSystemIds=array_map("getMobileSystemId",$systemList))
    {
        echo "Arrayfehler ArrayMap";
    }
```

Comment: There are always exactly 0 or 1 records fulfilling `WHERE sytemId=x` or can there be 2,3,4, ... ?

Comment: Have you checked the values inside the function?

Comment: Can you show your calls to the function, and some more of the PHP?  Is the function within a class?

Comment: @VolkerK no there is always one result.

Comment: @Jon Thats not in a class and everything before is great

Comment: Why use an array_map ? You're looking for a complicated solution for a simple problem... For example : have you considered using ONE query with the `IN` statement ?

Comment: After your function, before your `if`, what does `var_dump($systemList);` give?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, using a `return` in your function would be much cleaner.
Nothing to do with your problem, but is your `$systemId` var trusted ? (To prevent SQL injection).

Comment: Not really. That´s what I want to do later

Comment: I have fixed the return thing

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
if(!$mobileSystemIds=array_map("getMobileSystemId",$systemList))
{
    echo "Arrayfehler ArrayMap";
}
```

ought to read (just checked; it works for me):

```
$mobileSystemIds = array_map('getMobileSystemId', $systemsList);
if (empty($mobileSystemIds))
{
    if (empty($systemsList) || !(is_array($systemsList)))
        echo "OK: no mobile IDs, but no systems either";
    else
        echo "THIS now is strange :-(";
}
else
{
    echo "Alles OK";
    var_dump($mobileSystemIds);
}
```

I tried this by returning a dummy value based on input; if it does not work for you, there must be something strange in the database.

(Update: the text below refers to your *original* code, which did not use array mapping)

Your code *ought* to be working as it is. You put several `$mobileSystemId` 's into a single `$mobileSystemId`.

It works: I tested with a simpler code, removing the DB calls but leaving your code, and spelling, untouched.

So, the error must be elsewhere. I would guess that this code is included into something else, and:

- the `$mobileSystemIds = array();` declaration gets executed **more than once**, thereby losing all its data;
- the `$mobileSystemIds = array();` declaration is itself **included in a more local scope** and you read it from outside, reading an empty value or a totally different value.

Try replacing the first part of your code with:

```
GLOBAL $mobileSystemsIds;
if (defined($mobileSystemsIds))
    trigger_error("mobileSystemsId defined more than once", E_USER_ERROR);
else
    $mobileSystemsIds = array();
```

and also, in the function body:

```
if (!defined($mobileSystemsId))
    trigger_error("mobileSystemsId should have been defined", E_USER_ERROR);
```

Comment: I have looked on it again. I just declared the variable as an array once. Where should I put this code?

Comment: The first part replaces your current definition (actually it *adds* to your current definition), the second part I just added checks that it worked inside the function. **This will not solve the bug**, it will only confirm you where it is. Check "Variable scope" in the PHP manual.

Comment: No I always get the output "Arrayfehler Arraymap"

Comment: If I replace the array_map line with                                      if(!print_r(array_map("getMobileSystemId",$systemList)))
 {
  echo "Arrayfehler ArrayMap";
 }           I get "Array()"

Comment: OK: no mobile IDs, but no systems either

Comment: Oups! $systemList is empty!

Comment: "Behind every small problem there is a bigger problem waiting to come out" :-)